# Dealing with conflicting IDs in multiple instances of bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to have multiple instances of the same bootstrap tab markup in the DOM. Unfortunately it appears that bootstrap tabs mandate the use of IDs which means the same IDs conflict as IDs should by definition only occur once in the DOM tree.

Example, see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamish/u50hqso5/), the bottom Foo Bar tabs end up controlling the top tab pane since I've added multiple elements to the DOM with the same ID.

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#foo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bar" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="foo">Foo content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bar">Bar content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#foo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bar" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="foo">Foo content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bar">Bar content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I'm using Angular, as with any template engine, I can differentiate the IDs in the template with a scope variable and ensure that variable is unique throughout my application. Example, using {{id}} as a suffix.

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#foo{{id}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bar{{id}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="foo{{id}}">Foo content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bar{{id}}">Bar content</div>
  </div>
```

I'd like to know if there is a nicer way to solve this problem? Any way of configuring bootstrap to use class based selectors etc?

Comment: if the bar is a directive and you pass onto it the id I think its a great and simple solution for your problem. regarding bootstrap I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ui-bootstrap package](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs). It makes dealing with tabs way easier in Angular.